# Compactness in $R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am looking at the proof that the following statements are equivalent from Apostol's Mathematical Analysis.

Let $S$ be a subset of $R^n$.

b) $S$ is closed and bounded.

c) Every infinite subset of $S$ has an accumulation point in $S$.

Assume (c) holds. We shall prove (b). If $S$ is unbounded, then for every $m \gt 0$ there exists a point $\mathbf x_m$ in $S$ with $\parallel \mathbf x_m \parallel$ $\gt m$. The collection $T = \{\mathbf x_1, \mathbf x_2,... \}$ is an infinite subset of $S$ and hence, by (c), $T$ has an accumulation point $\mathbf y$ in $S$. But for $m \gt 1 + \parallel \mathbf y\parallel$ we have

$\parallel \mathbf x_m - \mathbf y \parallel$ $\ge$ $\parallel \mathbf x_m \parallel$ $-$ $\parallel \mathbf y \parallel$ $\gt$ $m$ $-$ $\parallel \mathbf y \parallel$ $\gt 1$,

contradicting the fact that $\mathbf y$ is an accumulation point of $T$. This proves that $S$ is bounded.

This is the part of the proof that I'm not clear. By way of contradiction, it has proven that for an open ball with center at $\mathbf y$ and radius 1, there exists a point $\mathbf x_m$ that does not intersect the ball. However, to complete the proof that $\mathbf y$ is not an accumulation point of $T$, isn't it necessary to show that there exists an open ball containing $\mathbf y$ that does not intersect with any points in $T$ not just a specific point?

Can anyone explain this to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping your notation, note that for every $n\geq M$, we have $\Vert \mathbf{x}_n\Vert >M$ by definition of the sequence. Hence, by the same argument, we can conclude that for such $n$, $\Vert \mathbf{x}_n-\mathbf{y}\Vert>1$. If $\mathbf{y}\neq\mathbf{x}_j$ for $1\leq j\leq m-1$ we can let $\delta=\min\{\Vert \mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}_1\Vert, \ldots,\Vert\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}_m-1\Vert, 1\}$. Note that $\delta>0$. Can you see that the ball with center at $\mathbf{y}$ and radius $\delta$ does not intersect any point of $T$?
If $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{x}_j$ for some $j$, let $\delta=\min\{\Vert \mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}_1\Vert, \ldots,\Vert\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}_j-1\Vert,  \Vert\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}_j+1\Vert,  \Vert\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}_m-1\Vert,1\}$ and the same ball as above will work.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a convergent sequence $x_n\to x, x_n\in S$.
There is an accumulation point $y\in S$ of the sequence.

With unicity of the limit, you have that $x=y$ hence $x\in S$.

---

Now let us prove that if
$$
\forall (x_n)\in S\ \ x_n\to x \implies x\in S
$$
then $S$ is closed.

---

Assume that $S$ is not closed. Let $S^c = \Bbb R^n - S$.
Then $S^c$ is not open, and you can find an $x\in S^c$ such as,
for every $n\in \Bbb N$,
$$
\exists x_n\in S^c \ \ \|x_n - x\|<\frac1n
$$
(this is the negation of the definition of an open set, with $\epsilon = 1/n$).

Then you have $x_n\to x, x_n\in S$, and $x\in S^c$. This ends the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the proof is stating that, except a finite number of points of the sequence, the distance of every other point with **y** is greater than 1. And so there does not exist infinite points in a given open set of **y**, which one needs to for **y** to be an accumulation point.

If you think about it, the definition that given an open set, you need **at least one** element of the sequence to be in it, implies that there are infinite number of elements in that open set, because we can construct a sequence of nested open balls, starting with the given open set, such that each ball is properly contained in the previous one and has an element of the sequence. Thus, this way you get infinite number of points of the sequence in the given open set.